# Window leaked error causing crash on boot

Tags: android, kotlin, dialog

My app should display a dialog box the first time its open, asking if the user wants a tutorial. I keep getting the following error tho.

```
android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.mypackage has leaked window DecorView@43aa395[Tutorial] that was originally added here ...
```

After doing some research, I found out it could be caused by changing activities while the dialogue is open. However, that only happens when a button is pressed, these buttons are outside of the dialogue.

```
        val tut = getSharedPreferences("tutorial", MODE_PRIVATE)
        val dialog = Dialog(this@MainActivity)

        if (tut.getBoolean("my_first_time", true)) { //if the app is being launched for first time, do something

            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.tutorial_dial) //sets xml tag
            dialog.setTitle("Tutorial") //idk what this does
            dialog.setCancelable(true) //this... confuses me, my guess is that it allows you to click off the dialogue box
            val button = dialog.findViewById<View>(R.id.yeah) as Button
            button.setOnClickListener {
                val intent = Intent(this, Tutorial1::class.java)
                dialog.dismiss()
                startActivity(intent)
            }
            val button2 = dialog.findViewById<View>(R.id.nahhhh) as Button
            button2.setOnClickListener {
                dialog.dismiss()
            }

            dialog.show()

            tut.edit().putBoolean("my_first_time", false).apply() // record the fact that the app has been started at least once
        }else{dialog.dismiss()}
```

The line that causes the error is `dialog.show()`

All help is appreciated

Comment: It looks like you are trying to show a `dialog` from a destroyed `activity`, you need to check if the `activity` is destroyed or not by using `isFinishing()`

Comment: @MouaadAbdelghafourAITALI, just wondering, where would I put the '''isFinishing()''' command?

Comment: Before showing the dialog : if(!isFinishing()) dialog.show()

Answer (score 0):

Add a check whether the activity is present or not, and if it is finishing. Add check like this:

```
if(getActivity() != null && !getActivity().isFinishing()) {
     dialog.show(); 
}
```

Comment: This makes sense, But now I have a ```No value passed for parameter 'p0'``` and ```Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type Activity?``` errors.